# Drawing a tree of folders and files dynamically in a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, tree

Is it possible to draw a tree of folers and files dynamically in a ASP.NET MVC 4 (c#) from a pathname and how can I deal that, please ? I have searched in the net, but I haven't found what I was looking for.

For example, like this tree :

```
C:
├───AdminScripts
├───iissamples
├───mailroot
│   ├───Badmail
│   ├───Drop
│   ├───Mailbox
│   ├───Pickup
│   ├───Queue
│   ├───Route
│   └───SortTemp
├───Scripts
└───wwwroot
    ├───aspnet_client
    │   └───system_web
    │       └───1_1_4322
    │           └───_vti_cnf
    ├───images
    ├───_private
    └───_vti_log
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yes, given you have the correct permissions, it's possible. What have you tried so far? You should look into the System.IO namespace, namely the File and Directory classes

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look of a few good javacript components that help you to complete task

some of them:

1. jquery-file-tree - http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/
2. el Finder - http://elfinder.org/
3. Kynki File Manager - http://www.bennadel.com/resources/projects/kinky_file_explorer/demo/?file=demo/index.cfm#content
4. FileManager - http://freewebfilemanager.com/filemanager/

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to make a tree of folders and files dynamically, so, there is no need to JavaScript as I guess

Answer (score 0):

Use Directory.GetDirectories - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx

You can then add all the directories into a tree in your code behind using

http://mvc.ext.net/#/TreePanel_Basic/Simple/

Note the source code link above the example to see how it works!

Comment: Good idea, I've tried to put the code behind in a View page base on Razor replacing `<script runat="server">` with `@{}`, but, this haven't work. How can I fix that, please ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? See this for example on how to load from a controller. When viewing the source code, note that there is a view and controller source available http://mvc.ext.net/#/TreePanel_Loaders/Direct_Method/